# tensorflow setup tool problem while installing in ubuntu16.04 LTS

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Currently i am using ubuntu16.04 and cncountered this problem while **installing tensorflow using pip**:

**ERROR: markdown 3.1 has requirement setuptools>=36, but you'll have setuptools 28.8.0 which is incompatible.**

Please help me in resolving this.

thanks in advance:)

Comment: Have you tried updating setuptools? It tells you the problem in the message.

Comment: no i didn't . could you tell me ?

Comment: [Maybe](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#id20)